# How to override PrimeFaces p:dataExporter wrongly exporting numbers as text in Excel?

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

The `PrimeFace` [`p:dataExporter`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/dataExporter.html) tag exports numeric data as text by default, which results in a cell with a green triangle in the upper left corner.  This can be seen in the [PrimeFaces showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml) as well, if you click the Excel export under the cars table.

How can I override this default to make sure my numeric columns are not exported as text?  I tried using the `postProcessor` attribute pointing to my method that sets the Excel format for all the data cells using `POI` API but that did not take effect (did not change anything):

```
public void formatExcel(Object doc) {
    HSSFWorkbook book = (HSSFWorkbook)doc;
    HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0); 

    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);
    int colCount = header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    HSSFCellStyle numStyle = book.createCellStyle();
    numStyle.setDataFormat((short)1);

    for(int rowInd = 1; rowInd < rowCount; rowInd++) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowInd);
        for(int cellInd = 1; cellInd < colCount; cellInd++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellInd);
            String val = cell.getStringCellValue();

            cell.setCellStyle(numStyle);

        }
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

but that gives me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
```

So that means that all data is indiscriminately exported as text and then you can't even change it afterwards.

Comment: In your postProcessor, you nowhere set the value of the cell to an integer. You set the type, but not the value.

Comment: the values are there already exported by PrimeFaces d:dataExporter

Comment: As strings. You have to set the new values as number! Just setting the cell type is not enough. (It is M$ you know, things do not work as you expect them (or it could be an omission in POI))

Comment: i just made a fix doing it exactly like you suggest but i think it is awkward and inelegant.  i wish there was a better solution

Comment: Details, details…  if you realy want a cleaner solution in YOUR code Download the source of POI, and override setter to not only apply a new cellType/cellStyle but also convert the value for you. Your code becomes cleaner, but the solution in general not.

Comment: I always insist upon using the Apache POI API on my own instead of being transparently dependent upon the `<p:dataExporter>` so that the code can easily be reused later in other applications that do not use PrimeFaces, if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me.  It is far from elegant but it works:

```
HSSFCellStyle intStyle = book.createCellStyle();
intStyle.setDataFormat((short)1);

HSSFCellStyle decStyle = book.createCellStyle();
decStyle.setDataFormat((short)2);

HSSFCellStyle dollarStyle = book.createCellStyle();
dollarStyle.setDataFormat((short)5);


for(int rowInd = 1; rowInd < rowCount; rowInd++) {
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowInd);
    for(int cellInd = 1; cellInd < colCount; cellInd++) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellInd);

        //This is sortof a hack to counter PF exporting all data as text
        //We capture the existing value as string, convert to int, 
        //then format the cell to be numeric and reset the value to be int
        String strVal = cell.getStringCellValue();

        //this has to be done to temporarily blank out the cell value
        //because setting the type to numeric directly will cause 
        //an IllegalStateException because POI stupidly thinks
        //the cell is text because it was exported as such by PF...
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

        strVal = strVal.replace(",", StringUtils.EMPTY);

        if(strVal.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            //integer
            //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)1);
            int intVal = Integer.valueOf(strVal);

            cell.setCellStyle(intStyle);
            cell.setCellValue(intVal);
        } else {
            //double
            if(strVal.startsWith("$")) {
                strVal = strVal.replace("$", StringUtils.EMPTY);
                //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)5);
                cell.setCellStyle(dollarStyle);
            } else {
                //numStyle.setDataFormat((short)2);
                cell.setCellStyle(decStyle);
            }

            double dblVal = Double.valueOf(strVal);
            cell.setCellValue(dblVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it far from elegant?

Answer (score 3):

In your postProcessor, you nowhere set the value of the cell to an integer. You set the type, but not the value. Setting the type is not enough. You have to convert value to a number and set it again